# Form Validation with password match

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have two forms inside my body:

```
<body>
    <form method=post name="signin">
        <table>
            <theader>Sign In</theader>
            <tr>
                <td>Email:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type=text length=25 maxlength=25 name=em id=em />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type=password length=15 maxlength=15 name=up id=up />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=2>
                    <input type=button value="submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <form method=post name="register">
        <table>
            <theader>Don't have an account? Register, it's Free!</theader>
            <tr>
                <td>Email:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type=text length=25 name=email id=email /><span id="nameerror"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type=password length=15 name=pass id=pass />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Confirm Password:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type=password length=15 name=cpass id=cpass /><span id="pwerror"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Account Type:</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="seltype">
                        <option name=standard SELECTED>Standard</option>
                        <option name=admin>Administrator</option>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=2>
                    <input type=button value="submit" onClick="JavaScript:validate();" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

I would like to do the following:
For each form, validate to ensure it's filled in and also for the second form I want to validate that the two password matched. I have the following:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var t = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("seltype").value;
    var k = document.getElementById("pass").value;
    var j = document.getElementById("cpass").value;

    $('#cpass').blur(function(){    
        if (k != j) {
            document.getElementById("pwerror").innerHTML = "Password does not match";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("pwerror").innerHTML = "Password matches";
        }
    }); 
});

function validate() {   
    if (t != null && y != null && k != null && j != null) {
    }
    if (t == "" || y == "" || k == "" || j == "") {
        alert("fill in");
    }
}
```

Comment: And what exactly isn't working ?

Comment: have you assigned id like 'id=pass'  without quotes ?

Comment: How and where do I send the form submission statement after validation?

Comment: @ZahidH, what you just asked in this previous comment, made no sense to with respect to the question made above. Do you mean, how to execute the validate() function on form submit?
Also, please edit your question to actually include your actual problem with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I preferred not to mix native JavaScript and validated using pure jQuery only. One of the benefits here is that the *empty* field check would work for any `<form>` since it's not tied to any particular form, input name or ids.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( 'form' ).submit(function(event) {
        var $form = $( this );
        var checkPass = true;
        $form.find( 'input' ).each(function( i, e) {
            if (e.value.length === 0) {
                event.preventDefault();
                alert(e.name + " cannot be empty");
                return (checkPass = false);
            }
        });
        if( checkPass && $form.is( '[name="register"]' ) ) {
            if( $form.find( '#pass').val() !== $form.find( '#cpass' ).val()) {
                event.preventDefault();
                alert( 'Passwords do not match.' );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Working Demo at **[JsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/CHbnd/)**

Answer (score 1):

Basics:

1. If you want to check if a variable is not null, ideally, you should use !== & not !=.
2. If you want to check if a variable is "", ideally, you should use === and not ==. 
   Check out: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp
3. Use JSFiddle.net to give a better working example of your code WHICH can help others see a demo of your actual code.
4. Your code currently has lot of scope for optimization. Since its just a basic validation you are trying to achieve, why do you need to use jQuery? Why not just use  JavaScript basic variable comparisons?
5. Google before you ask here. If its so straightforward, your question *will* get downvoted.
6. Alert is not the best way to notify the user to fill in. For example, your 'Password Matches' or 'Password Doesn't Match' div is a much better way to notify the user. Use Form Events to validate the form as the user is already filling in the details in the form!
7. Question responsibly by giving your exact problems and not just pasting the code! How would we know where you are facing a problem.
8. Variables work in Scope. Check the scope of variable before using them in different functions. For example, you define var t, y, k, j in first function and use it in second function - will throw up an error of undefined variable t.

From what information you provided, here's what I could help with:

**HTML:**

```
<form method=post name="signin">
    <table>
        <theader>Sign In</theader>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td>
                <input type=text length=25 maxlength=25 name=em id=em />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td>
                <input type=password length=15 maxlength=15 name=up id=up />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2>
                <input type=button value="submit" onclick="javascript:validateSignin()" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<form method=post name="register">
    <table>
        <theader>Don't have an account? Register, it's Free!</theader>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td>
                <input type=text length=25 name=email id=email /><span id="nameerror"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td>
                <input type=password length=15 name=pass id=pass />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Confirm Password:</td>
            <td>
                <input type=password length=15 name=cpass id=cpass /><span id="pwerror"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Account Type:</td>
            <td>
                <select id="seltype">
                    <option name=standard SELECTED>Standard</option>
                    <option name=admin>Administrator</option>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2>
                <input type=button value="submit" onClick="JavaScript:validateRegister();" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#cpass').blur(function () {
        if (k != j) {
            document.getElementById("pwerror").innerHTML = "Password does not match";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("pwerror").innerHTML = "Password matches";
        }
    });
});

function validateRegister() {
    var t = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("seltype").value;
    var k = document.getElementById("pass").value;
    var j = document.getElementById("cpass").value;

    if (t !== null && y !== null && k !== null && j !== null) {}
    if (t === "" || y === "" || k === "" || j === "") {
        alert("fill in");
    }
}
function validateSignin() {

    var se= document.getElementById("em").value;
    var sp= document.getElementById("up").value;

    if (se !== null && sp !== null){ }
    if (se === "" || sp === "") {
        alert("fill in");
    }
}

</script>
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thanks... Where is the code for submitting the form if everything passes?

Comment: Currently its not submitting anywhere. It will submit based on what you put in the "action" attribute of the "form" element. So `<form action="myFormHandler.php" method="post">` will send all the elements of the FORM to myFormHandler.php via "POST" method.